# How to make a copy of the OpenGL ES framebuffer in iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

I'd like to copy the OpenGL ES framebuffer from video RAM to video RAM in my iOS game.  How is this done?

Ideally I'll do this 30 times per second.  Then transfer the contents of the copied buffer to the CPU piecewise (not all at once since this causes a stutter in the game).

Comment: Are you asking for VRAM to VRAM, or VRAM to main RAM? Those are very, very different issues with very, very different answers.

Comment: Okay, it's just that your reference to 'transfer the contents of the copied buffer to the CPU' makes me think you actually want VRAM to main RAM.

Comment: You're correct in that I will eventually transfer the contents of the framebuffer copy to RAM.  However as a first step I want to copy the framebuffer from VRAM to VRAM... then transfer from VRAM to RAM piecewise to (hopefully) avoid stutters in the game.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'd say that JimN's answer regarding FBOs is a good approach.  In my experience there's a bit of weirdness in how PowerVR handles FBOs due to its deferred rendering mechanism, so if a bit of latency is okay you'll probably want to transfer the previous frame's data over to main RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I would say that you should have a look into Frame Buffer Objects (FBOs), you can find an example on the following post:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/23282#23282

This will allow you to render your scene into a texture attached to a FBO and use the texture afterwards.

PS: Thanks Christian for pointing out my mistake (I first read that MrMusic wanted to copy VRAM to RAM and wrongly suggested to use glReadPixels which is indeed unsuitable for that purpose).

Comment: He asks for VRAM to VRAM copy, which makes `glReadPixels` useless. Unless you had PBOs in mind, but in this case the answer should be updated.